# Running commands operating on files always results in permission denied errors

Tags: permissions, terminal, command-line, file-permissions

When I try executing commands operating on files, they always fail. I can't check permissions on the terminal because I'd have to run a command that operates on a file (directory) in order to do so. Here is an example of what I mean:

[image]

Note that the terminal already shows a "Permission denied" error message when I open it.

According to my file browser, the `/sdcard` symlink (I suppose it's a symlink) has all permissions set. However, on the path to the linked locations, not all permissions are set. To test whether this is what's causing the problem, I created a new directory `/t` with all permissions set. You can see the result of me running `ls` in that directory in the terminal output above.

[image]

What do I have to do in order to be able to run commands that operate on files?

My phone is a rooted OnePlus 3 running OxygenOS 5.0.1 which is based on Android 8.0.0. BusyBox is installed.

Comment: Are you using custom ROM? Your /system directory seems to have bad permissions. If you have root, try su -c "ls -l $(which ls)" or use $(which busybox) ls

Comment: I can't try stuff myself anymore because my phone died. However, I think I should leave this question open in case someone has an idea that probably works and someone else comes across this.